# A domain that used to be on Azure now has new dns but Azure 404 error still shows up. What to do?

Tags: azure, dns

My domain was previously hosted in another place (some years ago) and was connected to Azure. Some days ago I successfully changed the dns to a different hosting company but it seems I still get a webpage related to Azure when I try to access the website on my browsere. This is what is displayed:

> Error 404 - Web app not found.
>
> The web app you have attempted to reach is not available in this Microsoft Azure App Service region. This could be due to one of several reasons:
>
> 1. The web app owner has registered a custom domain to point to the Microsoft Azure App Service, but has not yet configured Azure to recognize it. Click here to read more.
> 2. The web app owner has moved the web app to a different region, but the DNS cache is still directing to the old IP Address that was used in the previous region. Click here to read more.

btw. I clicked the links and they are not helpful.

I have no idea how Azure works, but I have access to the login information. When I log in on portal.azure.com everything seems to be empty, there are no apps, only a canceled subscription and really nothing to see.

If I click "All resources", I get "No resources to display".
My first thought is that this is some kind of a cache problem, but I have cleared the cache in my browsers, tried different ISP and different computers in different continents, but I always get the same error message.

If I check whois.com and who.is I can see that the new dns is correct and the only thing that should be displaying is the temporary index.html page that is currently in the htdocs folder for the new host.

Do you know what I need to do to remove any connection to Azure and display my new website?

Comment: So is your subscription active still?

Comment: No, Azure subscription has been canceled.

Comment: What was the TTL set to on the DNS records? It's probably still cached.

Comment: Ok, now I might have solved it. I let the hosting take care of creating the dns entries, like I have done a million times before, but when I looked at them I saw that the A record was referring to the wrong ip. I changed that and added a cname record for www. Now, if I go to www.mydomain.com I get the correct website, if I go to mydomain.com, I still get Azure. But I am guessing, since TTL for A record is 900, I have to wait 15 minutes (although I am guessing, since I am not quite sure what all of these records mean).

Comment: And now it works.... Thanks for offering your time juunas. I guess it took creating a stackoverflow question to get my brain to start working.

Comment: Good to hear :) I didn't really directly help this time though :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved.
I just needed to edit my dns entries. For some reason, they were still pointing to an old IP.